# How do I divide cards into rows with every row having 4 cards

Tags: angular, mdbootstrap

I want to make a site similar to E-commerce with cards and I am using Angular and MdBootstrap UI Kit.

Suppose I have 18 cards, I want 4 rows of 4 cards and last row should have 2 cards.
My data for cards is coming from backend in json format.

But I am getting this Output.

[image: With the current code]

What I desire is this.

[image: Want to achieve this]

Code I have currently

**html:-**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" *ngFor='let row of grid'>
    <div class="col" *ngFor='let c of row'>
      <div style="margin: 10px">
        <mdb-card>
          <!--Card image-->
          <mdb-card-img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Lightbox/Thumbnail/img%20(97).jpg" alt="Card image cap"></mdb-card-img>
          <!--Card content-->
          <mdb-card-body>

            <!--Title-->
            <mdb-card-title>
              <h4>{{c}}</h4>
            </mdb-card-title>

            <!--Text-->
            <mdb-card-text> Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
              content.
            </mdb-card-text>

            <a href="#" mdbBtn color="primary" mdbWavesEffect>Button</a>
          </mdb-card-body>
        </mdb-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ts:-**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  cards: number;
  grid: number[][];
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cards = 18;
    this.gridgenerator();
  }

  gridgenerator(): number[][] {
    let last = this.cards % 4;
    let rows =
      this.cards % 4 === 0
        ? new Array(Math.floor(this.cards / 4))
        : new Array(Math.floor(this.cards / 4 + 1));
    this.grid = new Array(rows);
    for (let r = 0; r < rows.length; r++) {
      if (r === rows.length - 1) {
        this.grid[r] = new Array(last);
      } else {
        this.grid[r] = new Array(4);
      }
    }
    console.log(this.grid);

    return this.grid;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use CSS flexbox instead to achieve this.

Comment: @AakashVerma Aakash, can you please elaborate with a code example?

Comment: @AakashVerma How will I make sure that at max only 4 cards appear in a row with flexbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [working angular example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5qtjjl), using only the flex properties.

The host element is a flex container and has the following css properties :

```css
:host {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

while the mdb-card is a flex item with the following properties :

```css
mdb-card {
  margin: 10px;
  flex-basis: calc(25% - 2 * 10px); // 25% minus left and right margins.
}
```

No need of .row and .col elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just for your code to work, you need to **define the width of each card** and not just margin.

Defining no width allows a `div` to take up entire space available according to it at a block level and that's what's happening for the last two cards. It's expanding whenever it's getting a chance to because its children need the space.

Using `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` along with definite width of the card will give you the result you need. You'd probably need to set `justify-content` to suit your requirements.

**Now, it's difficult to keep only four (or n) cards in a row using flex given that your screen size to card size ratio can vary, but you can set a parent, of calculated width, over all the cards, to make sure there can be only 4 children at a time.**

I have made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8tfwbv36/) for you to check. Try expanding the result window and re-running to see what I am talking about).

Check [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/) for reference.

Comment: Thanks Aakash but I rather not define width and height of each card because then it makes the entire setup less responsive. Awesome reference though

Comment: Glad you liked it. Width defined in rem or % is always responsive. There’s no other way even JavaScript can help you with that.